# Buffer specific remap of a global map to a plugin command

Tags: key-bindings

I have this in my .vimrc as global for `gf`: `map gf :edit <cfile><cr>` from the help on gf, but I want to remap `gf` in markdown files for a plugin command with the following:

```
autocmd FileType markdown nnoremap <buffer>gf <Plug>Markdown_EditUrlUnderCursor
```

When running `:nmap` I see the following output:

```
n  ge           @<Plug>Markdown_EditUrlUnderCursor
n  gx           @<Plug>Markdown_OpenUrlUnderCursor
n  gf          *@<Plug>Markdown_EditUrlUnderCursor
```

but `gf` doesn't do what it should. I see the little star there and I guess it has something to do with it, but I have no idea what that means. `ge` works as expected. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to map a `<Plug>` mapping always use `nmap` not `nnoremap`.

Basically a `<Plug>(Something)` is a sequence of chars that are mapped to some functionality.

Imagine you have:

```
" you have some mapping
nnoremap a :echo "hello"<CR>
" and want remap that mapping
nmap b a

" same
nnoremap asdf :echo "world"<CR>
nmap b asdf

" same
nnoremap <Plug>(hello) :echo "hello world"<CR>
nmap gf <Plug>(hello)
```

Comment: I tried with `nmap` afterwards, but it seems vim has already saved the bad map and would not overwrite, so that's where my confusion came from.

Comment: Just as a note for other people: deleting ~/.vim/view removes these old configs.